# How to fix the direction and body problems?

Tags: javascript

i'm a rookie and i try to learn by myself from different sources html css and now i'm on the block of JS
I'm actually doing a snake game  but i have differents issues , the body of my snake supposed to be 3 blocks width , and he is also supposed to move  with the arrow key !!

I'm kind stuck and request your knowledge to let me find the light again :)

//* I'm french and hope my english is correct *//

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var canvasWidth = 900;
    var canvasHeight = 600;
    var blockSize = 30;
    var ctx;
    var delay = 100;
    var snakee;


    init();

    function init()
    {

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
        canvas.height = canvasHeight;
        canvas.style.border = "1px solid"
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        snakee = new Snake([[6,4],[5,4],[4,4],[3,4],[2,4]], "right");
        refreshCanvas();
       
    }
    
    function refreshCanvas()
    {
        
        ctx.clearRect (0,0,canvasWidth, canvasHeight);  
        snakee.draw();
        snakee.advance();
        setTimeout(refreshCanvas, delay);
    }

    function drawBlock(ctx, position)
     {
        var x = position[0] * blockSize;
        var y = position[1] * blockSize;
        ctx.fillRect(x ,y , blockSize , blockSize );

     }

    function Snake(body, _direction)
    {
        this.body = body;
        this.direction = "right";
        this.draw = function ()
        {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle =  "#ff0000";
            for(var i = 0; i < this.body.lenght; i++);
            {
                drawBlock(ctx, this.body[i]);
            }
               ctx.restore();

        };
        this.advance = function()
        {
            var nextPosition = this.body[0].slice();
            switch(this.direction)
            {
                case "left":
                    nexPosition[0] -= 1;
                    break;
                case "right":
                    nextPosition[0] += 1;
                    break;
                case "down":
                    nextPosition[1] -= 1;
                    break;
                case "up":
                    nextPosition[1] += 1;
                    break;
                default:
                        throw("Invalid Direction");
            
            }
            this.body.unshift(nextPosition);
            this.body.pop();
        };
        this.setDirection = function(newDirection)
        {
            var allowedDirections;
            switch(this.direction)
            {
                case "left":   
                case "right":  
                    allowedDirections = ["up", "donw"];
                    break;                
                case "down":
                case "up":
                    allowedDirections = ["left","right"]
                    break;
                default:
                        throw("Invalid Direction");
            
            }
            if(allowedDirections.indexOf(newDirection) > -1 )
            {
                this.direction = newDirection;
            }
        };
    }
}


document.addEventListener = function handleKeyDown(e)
{
    const key = e.keyCode;
    var newDirection;
    switch(key)
    {
        case 37:
            newDirection = "left";
            break;
        case 38:
            newDirection = "right";
            break;
        case 39:
            newDirection = "up";
            break;
        case 40:
            newDirection = "down";
            break;
        default:
            return; 
    }
    snakee.setDirection(newDirection);
    
}
```

Comment: What should happen when the snake reaches the edge of the canvas?  Now it seems he runs away and never returns.

Comment: I should add a function game over , and also add an alert with "Game over" (press space bar ton restart) , it follow a tuto and with all this new language that i'm not used to it's a bit messy .

Comment: I don't know where to start to learn well, I want to try to train to become a web developer.
Is this the right way to learn?

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener is a function and takes at least two arguments

```
it should be:

    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {

         let code = e.keyCode;
    })
```

Where the first arg is the type of event to handle and the second is the callback - handling the event.

I've noticed a few bugs in your code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.body.*lenght*; i++); << remove semicolon, lenght is typo
```

- 

```
            case "down":
                nextPosition[1] -= 1;  << should incrementing
                break;
            case "up":
                nextPosition[1] += 1;  << should decrementing
                break;
```

- 

Also the addEventListener code should be inside the window.onload statement
or else it will not see the snakee object.

This code simply won't work for a full blown snake program, because
each block of the snake can have a *separate direction*, but it's a start.